# Is there a way to detect the running app, while my app is in the background in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I need to detect the running application when my ios app is in the background. Basically I need to know if the user launched the Safari app?

Is there any way to do this? as I know when an app is in background, it may suspended or it could do only a minimal of things. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can only detect if your app is going to the background, no info is available regarding others apps.

Answer (score 2):

One caveat is that within your app, you can test for another app being available:

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

This can tell you whether the current device has a specific application installed IF that application is setup to handle url schemes for launching from another app.

[Apple's Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks ElJay, but in my application I need to check if a user launch the Safari app, when user was using my application. As my application is kind a exam-test application I need to check if the users launch Safari to search answers online.

Comment: Are you using URL's in your app?  If the user taps a url within your application you can safely assume that Safari will be launched.

Comment: I am not using any URL's in my application. It has only questions with some options to select. I just wanted be sure that users has not searched the answers from the internet. I understand there are hundreds of other web browsers for iPhone. But I need to find a way to check atleast for Safari. So basically if a user minimize my app and launched Safari, then the server needs to be notified that the test attempt is invalid. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can always check if the application was suspended, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such way. Anything you're trying to know outside the scope of your app is forbidden by Apple.